# Arithmetic overflow during SQL transaction

Tags: sql, type-conversion, sybase

Why does inserting '0001-01-01 00:00:01' to a DATETIME field cause an error ?

It's telling me :

> Arithmetic overflow during implicit conversion of VARCHAR value
>   '0001-01-01 00:00:01' to a DATETIME field . SQLState:  ZZZZZ
>   ErrorCode: 247

Isn't this a semantic analysis of my request ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Sybase online docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35400.1550/html/osref/osref281.htm), the minimum value supported by the datetime type is January 1, 1753 00:00:00.000